# Output returning no. of strings equal to the input string's word

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem with this code :

```
string answer;
cin >> answer;

while(answer != "S" && answer != "N" && answer != "s" && answer != "n")
{
    cout << "\n[!] Phrase [!] \n" << endl;
    cin >> answer;
}
```

Basically, whenever I input more than just a word, it prints out more than just one string.

Like, if I input "Hi", it prints out just one "[!] Phrase [!]" string.
But if I input something like "Hi bye", it prints out two "[!] Phrase [!]" strings.

Any fix for that?

Thanks

Comment: I think there might be a duplicate somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `>>` operator stops when it encounters whitespace and leaves the rest of the line for the next read. Use [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read the whole line:

```
std::getline(std::cin, answer);
```